# Ruby on rails: How to send an AJAX request to rails controller from login popup along with user given credentials

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Also, how to use the values entered in the popup, in the javascript function: `login_request()` which is being called on click, which will send the AJAX request eventually.

Note: The code snippet includes all the fields enclosed in the popup.

```html
<input class="csrf-token" type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="">
<div class="form-row clearfix">
  <label class="lbl-fld">Email ID</label>
  <input type="email" name="user[email]" ng-model="loginForm.email" placeholder="me@example.com" ng-required="true"/>
  <!--<span class="valid-chk">-->
  <!--<i ng-class="{'false':'icon-close', 'true': 'icon-correct'}[form['user[email]'].$valid]"></i>-->
  <!--</span>-->
</div>
<div class="form-row clearfix">
  <label class="lbl-fld">PASSWORD</label>
  <input type="password" name="user[password]" placeholder="password" ng-required="true"/>
  <!--<span class="valid-chk">-->
  <!--<i ng-class="{'false':'icon-close', 'true': 'icon-correct'}[form['user[password]'].$valid]"></i>-->
  <!--</span>-->
</div>
<div class="btn-container clearfix">
  <div class="btn-wrap">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="LOGIN" ng-click="login_request()" />
  </div>
  <div class="loader-wrapper" ng-show="loading" style="bottom: 25px;left: -53px;position: absolute;width: 25px;">
    <img class="loader-img-common" src="<%= asset_path('loader.gif') %>" style="max-width: 100%;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: use this link to understand ajax in rails. https://richonrails.com/articles/basic-ajax-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: It would help if you used `erb` on here instead of pure HTML, can you post your actual view code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function login_request(data_to_send)
 {
   $.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'controller/action',
   data: { key: "value" key_1: "value_1" },
   success: function(data) {
   // paste your code here after success
   }
  });
}  


  #in your config/route.rb

      match 'controller/action', :to => 'controller#action' ,:via => [:get,:post] # i'm using get as well as post also.

  #hope that help you. if you face any problem please let me know
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I figured it out eventually.