# placing a to_json response into ajax call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

So i have a `@` Variable with a bunch of json text.

I'm wanting this `@` var to be placed into my js script so that all the json will be inside the javascript ajax call. However if i make the var on the shwo page like this

```
var json = '<%= @json %>';
```

if i put var inside the url of my ajax call like this

```
url: json,
```

It throws up an 404 error. I'm guessing that its because it's looking for the url "json"?

Thanks for any advice!

**Edit**

```
@fl = Flight.all
@json = @fl.to_json
```

that is the part in my show that was requested

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: json ,
    success: function(json) {
        debugger;
```

It doesnt hit the debugger

Comment: Update your question with what is in your @json variable and the full ajax function

Comment: I would, However everything in hte ajax is private information, I could show some however it wouldnt be of any use. I can show the @json Var, Will show now

Comment: @CristianoAlencar Done!

Comment: That's not enough. I'm not asking you for private information. You could post your json and ajax function changing sensitive data by dummy data of same type.

Comment: Are you trying to send this data in the request? I'm a bit confused as to why your json object is in the url parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your url parameter should receive a string describing the path at where submission must be sent to (such as '/my-url').

Passing a json object will let ajax submit request to an undesirable path.

404 code describes exactly that. There is no route to where submission is being made. Thus rails can't handle that.

If you want to pass that json object to server you should set the 'data' parameter with your json object (instead of your 'url' parameter)

Comment: Hi, So i added the data param rather than url,  Still doesn't work. Still get a 404

Comment: Inside your console run 'rake routes' and make sure you have the route you're sending the request to. Furthermore make sure that the method type is properly set (is it 'GET', 'POST', 'PATCH' ?).

Comment: You should check your rails log as well so that you know where your request is being sent to and what is the method being used

Comment: That might be where im goign wrong, The `@json = fl.to_json` is in the show function, then this is on the show page that the js file is linked too `var json = '<%= @json %>';`

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing just see what value you are getting in @json,

```
   @fl = Flight.all        
   @json = @fl.to_json   
   puts @json.inspect
```

The @json variable has values somthing like this

"{\"id\":somevalue,\"key_1\":\"somevale\",\"created_at\":\"2015-11-01T15:39:31.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2015-11-01T15:39:31.000Z\",\"key_2\":somevalue}"

And you are trying to hit this url (which of course is not a url) through ajax which will give you 404 not found

Have a look on this you will get some idea  [Ruby on rails: How to send an AJAX request to rails controller from login popup along with user given credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606464/ruby-on-rails-how-to-send-an-ajax-request-to-rails-controller-from-login-popup/34608877#34608877)

Hope this helps you

Please let me know if you face some problem :)

Comment: Hey, I used byebug and got the exact same format back :) I'll look at that shortly :)

Comment: Hey, Tried the link you sent, I got a unexpected issue with a comma. Annoyingly this is the only thing stopping me at the moment :(

Comment: i think there should be a comma before ( :to => 'controller#action') , i have corrected there also now check

Comment: Not yet, I attempted it again and it didnt work again :(

Comment: @SamRoberts : If u r still facing problem send me the code @ ashwinidx@gmail.com :)