# Rails 4 : Input text box to search without submit button on index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my rails application on Customer index page I need a text input box without a submit button next to it. I just want to type customer number inside it and on pressing enter button the search should work. How to implement it ?

```
            <div class="row">
              <%= form_tag customers_path, :method => 'get', class: 'input-group'  do %>
                <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Search Customers' %>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <%= submit_tag "search", class: "btn btn-success btn-md" %>
                </span>
              <% end %>
            </div>
```

I have placed it on top of my index page of customers page just above the customer number column, So I don't want this search box plus the button to take a big space in my view. So I don't need the submit button. Or is there any way to replace the search button with a right pointing arrow button(bootstarp) to save space in my view.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide your submit button with `display: none;`. The form will still submit on enter.

You may also add another link with an image and the trigger the form's submit when the link is clicked. Or you can even style the button as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly remove the submit button from your code and trigger an event on pressing enter button,something like this.

```
    $('#search').keypress(function (e) 
       {
          if (e.which == '13') {
            get the character typed in the text box and send the parameters
            to controller-action thorugh ajax
               }
            });
```

take a reference from here how to send ajax to controller-action

[Ruby on rails: How to send an AJAX request to rails controller from login popup along with user given credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606464/ruby-on-rails-how-to-send-an-ajax-request-to-rails-controller-from-login-popup/34608877#34608877)
           In your controller/action it will be 
        performing select operation from database

```
     select bla bla from xyz where column like %params reveived from ajax%

      return it to the calling ajax function
```

Hope that's helps you